# Why do I have to hot reload flutter for the future builder to return

Tags: flutter, future, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a problem where when i launch the assignment page from the phone no List is returned by the future but when I hot reload a list is returned.

Here is the Future code that fetches the list from Sqflite database.

```
 Future\<List\<Road\>\> fetchARoad(int ClientID) async {
final db = \_db;
if (db == null) {
return \[\];
}
var read = await db.query('ROAD',
distinct: true,
columns: \[
'RoadID',
'RoadName',
'RoadNo',
'FName',
'LName',
'EId',
'ESubId',
'StationName',
'OicName',
'Lane',
'CarriageWay',
'ClientID'
\],
orderBy: 'RoadID',
where: "ClientID = ?",
whereArgs: \[ClientID\]);
// final road = read.map((row) =\> Road.fromRow(row)).toList();
List\<Road\> roadlist =
read.isNotEmpty ? read.map((e) =\> Road.fromRow(e)).toList() : \[\];
return roadlist;

}
```

Here is the future builder code:

```
 FutureBuilder<List<Road>>(
            future: _roadStorage.fetchARoad(widget.currentClientId.toInt()),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('No data available.');
              } else { 
              final roads = snapshot.data as List<Road>;
              print(roads);
              return 
                   Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: roads.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final road = roads[index];
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              tileColor: Colors.white60,
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const VehiclePage()));
                              },
                              leading: Text(
                                'ID:${road.ClientID}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                road.roadName,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                roadi.eFname,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  
            }
            },
          ),
```

I have tried change the Future to a Stream but I still get the same issue.
I just can't tell where the problem is because I not getting any errors.

Comment: you should return the `ListView.builder` from a if condition where it checks `if(snapshot.hasData)`

Comment: Thanks, but i still get the same issue.

Comment: try adding more specific condition as `hasData AND connectionState.done` (done or completed)

Answer (score 0):

So, I did not find a solution for the issue of having to reload to fetch data by 'ClientID' from database, so I decide to fetch all records then filter the records using 'Stream' 'where' method.

Like so:

```
 Stream<List<Road>> roadsById(int ClientID) {
return _streamController.stream.map((roads) {
  return roads.where((road) => road.ClientID == ClientID).toList();
});
```

Hope it saves someone from much headache.